# DBMS_SQL.column value error .. dynamic cursors

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, cursor

I am having troubling figure out error on following code

```
DECLARE
    CR_QUERY                INTEGER;
    CR_HANDLE               INTEGER;        
    V_COL1          VARCHAR2(40);
    V_COL2          VARCHAR2(18);
    N_ACTION                NUMBER(3);
    T_CREATE_TS             TIMESTAMP(6);
    V_COL3          VARCHAR2(60);

BEGIN
    CR_QUERY := DBMS_SQL.OPEN_CURSOR;
    DBMS_SQL.PARSE (CR_QUERY, I_V_QUERY, DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (CR_QUERY, 1, V_COL1, 40);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (CR_QUERY, 2, V_COL2, 18);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (CR_QUERY, 3, N_ACTION, 3);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (CR_QUERY, 4, T_CREATE_TS, 6);
    DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN (CR_QUERY, 5, V_COL3, 60);

    CR_HANDLE := DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (CR_QUERY);
    LOOP
        BEGIN
            EXIT WHEN DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS (CR_HANDLE) = 0;

            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (CR_QUERY, 1, V_COL1, N_COLERR, I_ACTUAL_LEN);
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (CR_QUERY, 2, V_COL2, N_COLERR, I_ACTUAL_LEN);
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (CR_QUERY, 3, N_ACTION, N_COLERR, I_ACTUAL_LEN);
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (CR_QUERY, 4, T_CREATE_TS, N_COLERR, I_ACTUAL_LEN);
            DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (CR_QUERY, 5, V_COL3, N_COLERR, I_ACTUAL_LEN);
```

the error is **Error(41,5): PLS-00307: too many declarations of 'COLUMN_VALUE' match this call**.

can someone suggest whats going ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE (CR_QUERY, 4, T_CREATE_TS, N_COLERR, I_ACTUAL_LEN);
```

If you define the variable T_CREATE_TS as a DATE it should work fine, but COLUMN_VALUE doesn't have a declaration where VALUE is of type TIMESTAMP (at least not in 10.2), so it throws the error.

Comment: `T_CREATE_TS` has value upto millisecods, wouldn't declaring a date variable and fetching its value in it will discard this data?

Comment: @Em Ae - That is correct, so you may have to convert it to a string using TO_CHAR in the query and then use a VARCHAR variable in your COLUMN_VALUE call.